# deleting iOS app and reinstall - retains data

Tags: ios

An app I use on iOS, which I recently deleted and reinstalled , somehow retains my login and user data - it doesn't seem to store anything in iCloud documents, so I'm not sure how it retains data.
What methods are there it could use to do this and how would users completely reset data for any app that does this?

Comment: It probably stores on its own server in the cloud, but this isn't a programming question and is too broad for this forum.

Comment: It probably stored in keychain: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9

Comment: thanks but I'm not clear how the app/specific user could be verified by the server now that apple has prevented developers from using IMEI or UDID as of iOS7.  Any ideas how they can still retain data locally on the device  after the app being deleted and reinstalled (keychain turned off so not that) - note that no login or user details are given to the app after re installing - yet unique user data is pulled from the server.